# edit simple_form shows associated model ids instead of name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form, simple-form-for

I am using simple_form in edit form but when showing associated attributes it shows id instead of name

Here is part of the code

```
= simple_form_for (@organization,url: admin_organizations_path) do |f|
  f.input name
  f.packages, label_method: :package_name, value_method: :id
```

It shows organization name but showing package id instead of name

`Organization.first.packages.name` gives name of the package.
this name is required to show on text field instead of id.

I am using neo4j

**Organization.rb**

```
has_many :out, :packages, rel_class: :OrganizationPackage
```

**Package.rb**

```
has_many :in, :organizations, rel_class: :OrganizationPackage
```

Help me anything am i missing.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use f.associations for your associations, just pass f.associations :packages rest simple form for will take care of it. For making it as input element you will need to enable, accepted nested attributes to create new one's.

Answer (score 1):

`= simple_form_for @organization do |f|
    f.input name
    f.association :packages`

and in your method initialize the organization

@organization = Organization.new

Comment: again it hits `undefined method 'options' for`

Comment: It is my edit page, so i used `@organization = Organization.find params[:id]`

Comment: kindly paste association of models.